# How can I make my iPad secure using my own(password protected) application in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ipad, passwords

I built an app for password key.As the user enters the correct password key he can access the app. But the thing is I want to apply this password key to my ipad itself aso that when the user switch on the ipad it should ask for password key.if the user enters correct password then he can see the information in iPad.

Guy's please give me an idea for this.

Anyone's help will me much appreciated.

Thank's to all,
Monish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. iOS authentication is not customizable by applications. (Neither is Android's, for what it's worth.)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can limit the authentication to your app only, but you can't do anything regarding iOS authentication.(In simple words not allowed).